# Bounded bilinear mapping is infinitely differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

I'm reading the first couple of chapters of "Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications" by J. E. Marsden and T. Ratiu.

Exercise 2.3-1 at page 73 asks the reader to prove that given normed linear spaces $ E $, $ F $ and $ G $, the composition (bounded, bilinear) mapping
$$
\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{L}} B\colon \Hom(F,G)\times \operatorname \Hom(E,F)\to \Hom(E,G)
$$
is $ \mathcal C^\infty $. If someone wonders, what $ B $ does is taking two bounded linear mappings $ T\in \Hom(E,F) $ and $ S\in \Hom(F,G) $, and returning their composite $ S\circ T $. Of course, $ \Hom(E,F) $ is the (normed) space of bounded linear functions $ E\to F $.

I tried to tackle a more general problem, that is, proving that any bounded bilinear map
$$
u\colon E\times F\to G
$$
is $ \mathcal C^\infty $.

Up to now I managed to show that $ u $ is $ \mathcal C^1 $, but I was not able to go further and (say) setup ad adequate induction argument to complete the task. Could someone provide me any hint or (preferably) a disturbingly detailed proof?

Comment: Look at the explicit formula for the first derivative. The right side will involve $B$ composed with various linear maps, so it's $C^1$. If you actually keep going, the third derivative vanishes so that trivially gives $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! $ \newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{L}}\newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}} $ I have shown that differential of $ u $ at $ (a,b) $ is the bounded linear map $ \diff u(a,b) = u({-},b)\circ \pi_E + u(a,{-})\circ \pi_F $ from the product space $ E\times F $ to $ G $, where the $ \pi $s are the projections. So we can write the function $ \diff u\colon E\times F\to \operatorname L(E\times F, G) $ as $ \diff u({+_1},{+_2}) = \Hom(\pi_E,G)\circ u({-},{+_2}) + \Hom(\pi_F,G)\circ u({+_1},{-}) $ and this shows that $ \diff u $ is again linear and thus differentiable. Continues below.

Comment: $ \newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}} $ The differential of $ \diff u $ at $ (a,b) $ is then

\begin{aligned}
\diff{(\diff u)}(a,b) &= \diff\left(\Hom(\pi_E,G)\circ u({-},{+_2})\right)(a,b) + \diff\left(\Hom(\pi_F,G)\circ u({+_1},{-})\right)(a,b)\\ &= \Hom(\pi_E,G)\circ u({-},{+_2}) + \Hom(\pi_F,G)\circ u({+_1},{-})
\end{aligned}
and thus $ \diff(\diff u) $ is constant. Does this suffice to prove the theorem I'm overthinking it?

Comment: yes, the proof goes along these lines. Though, if you want to do it inductively, we already know the base case ($u$ is $C^1$), so suppose it is $C^k$. Then, $du_{(a,b)}= u(\cdot,b)\circ\pi_E+u(a,\cdot)\circ\pi_F$. From this explicit formula, we see that $u$ being $C^k$ (and the things being composed are linear maps so they are easily seen to be $C^{\infty}$) implies $du$ is $C^k$ (I'm assuming you've proved the regularity of chain rule: if $f,g$ are $C^k$ then so is $f\circ g$, even in Banach spaces), which by definition means $u$ is $C^{k+1}$. Thus, by induction it is $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Okay, It's all clear now! The "big theorem" I'm tackling at the moment is exactly the regularity of the chain rule, and the proof in the book I'm using exploits at some point the fact that $ B $ (the composition bilinear form I define in OP) is $ \mathcal C^\infty $.